# jQuery (or textOverflow) taking too long

Tags: jquery

When we detect Firefox, we call

```
jQuery('.trunc').textOverflow();
```

but if the page is long, Firefox puts up the "unresponsive script" alert. I believe the actual problem is in the initial jQuery call (when it finds all matching DOM elements by their CSS).

I'm no jQuery expert but it looks like it really favors a style where it builds up lists of selected items and passes them down a chain. So there may not be a great workaround. But, is there one? I don't care about chaining, I just want to send textOverflow to relevant elements.

Comment: Do the types of elements which can have the .trunc class differ ? You may be able to make this selector more specific yielding better performance.

Comment: is this a function you have to call on $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Don’t really know the answer to the types of elements (I’m trying to maintain old code). Turns out the selection isn’t the speed hit though. And I don’t know when it is called. That wouldn’t make a difference in blocking the UI thread, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how many elements you are talking about, however the class selector you have should be very fast in Firefox, even with many elements.  This is because Firefox supports the `getElementsByClassName` native method... so the selector you have would essentially be the same as a call to `document.getElementsByClassName("trunc")`.

I think that the culprit would be the `textOverflow` calls because Firefox doesn't natively support this CSS feature, so I'd imagine the textOverflow plugin would be doing a lot of string processing/DOM/CSS manipulation to get the proper text-overflow behavior.

You could test this out by just calling the selector without the `textOverflow()` call and see how long it takes:

```
var truncElements = $('.trunc');
```

If the code above runs quickly on your large pages in Firefox, then I'd blame textOverflow.

Comment: Yeah, it took a while to test (deploying onto the fully loaded server) but the $() part is quick and the textOverflow() is what kills things. So there’s no standard jQuery way to break up that call?

Comment: David, no I don't think there is a standard jQuery way to break up that call.  What you CAN do is use `window.setTimeout` and execute the `textOverflow()` call in batches.  This basically means splitting out the calls to `textOverflow` into groups, allowing the browser to keep up and not issue script warnings.  I can try to whip up a quick example if you would like?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing that. I was just hoping that jQuery would have a way do do that for free (and perhaps more efficiently, by having a way to batch them into groups rather than singly). Maybe it's not a common enough issue, but it seems to come up from time to time (before I was touching jQuery code).

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of a shot in the dark, but you may want to try altering the selector to include the tag name as well. Since this avoids querying the entire DOM, and limits it to just those tags, it will be more efficient.

```
jQuery('span.trunc').textOverflow();
```

Replace span with the relevant tag. Not sure if it'll make a difference, but it's more efficient anyways :)

Good luck!

Comment: I should mention that this will primarily make a difference when used in a browser that hasn't implemented `document.getElementsByClassName` method.